# Как работает шаблон NavigationDrawer в AndroidStudio, где обрабатывать нажатия на навигационной панели?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-navigation-drawer

Всем здрасьте!
Не могу никак понять, где в шаблоне, который генерирует Android Studio, вешать обработки нажатия на соответствующую позицию? Есть подозрение, что в onNavigationDrawerItemSelected, но я когда пробовал делать обработку в нем, никакой реакции, может там какие-то особенности есть? Вот код ниже, где я могу хотя бы Тосты повесить, чтобы отследить нажатия, в каком методе это делается? Может кто-нибудь простой пример показать? Все лишнее я вроде поубирал, должен был остаться только шаблон, каким его генерирует AndroidStudio 1.3.2.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

public Document doc = null;
public Elements elementsTitle = null;
public Elements elementsAnnounce = null;
public ArrayList<News> newsList = new ArrayList<>();

private SimpleAdapter adapter;
private ListView listViewNews;
private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> data;

final String ATTRIBUTE_TITLE = "title";
final String ATTRIBUTE_ANNOUNCE = "announce";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
            break;
        case 5:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section5);
            break;
        case 6:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section6);
            break;
        case 7:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section7);
            break;
        case 8:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section8);
            break;
        case 9:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section9);
            break;
        case 10:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section10);
            break;
        case 11:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section11);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: Ну а фрагменты-то заменяются при вызове `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Нет, не заменяются. Собственно, не совсем понимаю, по какому принципу они там должны меняться, должна же быть привязка определенного фрагмента к position в ListView drawer'a насколько я понимаю (иначе как определить, какой фрагмент должен подставляться), а где эту привязку и как сделать?

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что запустили проект-шаблон, а он не работает?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ну, в шаблоне фрагмент только один, NavigationDrawerFragment. А вот фрагменты, которые будут переключаться - надо создавать самому насколько я понимаю. Вопрос в том, к чему и как их привязывать после создания?

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее будет сделать такой код

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerToggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item_settings:
               startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
               return true;
            default:
               return true;
         }
    }

}
```